# Using computed properties on FatFree mapper object (not retrieved from database)

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I know I can have a metod like this, in my class that extends `\DB\SQL\Mapper`:

```
public function getAll()
{
  $this->upperBody = 'upper(body)';
  $all = $this->find();
  return $all;
}
```

Then, when called, this model will have a virtual(computed) property `upperBody` which will hold the uppercased value of `body` field in database.

But then I am limited only to what the underlying database engine offers in terms of functions.

Is it possible somehow to use these on-the-fly fields like this:

```
$this->stripped_tags = strip_tags($this->body);
```

Assuming of course we have an existing `body` field in a database?

If not, then how would I go about writing my own filter to use in templates,thus having instead `{{@post.body|strip_tags}}`... or for example `{{@post.body|excerpt 30}}`.

I solved this, by using `cast()`:

```
    foreach ($this->model->getAll() as $p) {

        $c = $p->cast();
        $c[ 'excerpt' ] = chop_string( strip_tags($c[ 'body' ], '<p>'), $this->excerpt_limit);
        $all_posts[] = $c;
    }

    $f3->set('posts', $all_posts);
```

But it seems there must be a more elegant way to do this, as here I double the array processing just to assign one new computed property.

So is there a way to do it all in one go?

**AMEND 1:** As @ikkez suggested I tried doing this:

In my model class I added a property called `upperTitle` like so:

```
public $upperTitle;
```

Then in controller I have code like this:

```
$this->mdlPost->upperTitle = strtoupper($this->mdlPost->title);
```

After querying a database using `$this->mdlPost->paginate(...,...,...)`
and var_dumping, `upperTitle` is an empty string.

**AMEND 2:** (suggested in comment by @ikkez)

```
public function __construct(\DB\SQL $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
        parent::__construct($db, 'posts');

        $this->onload(function($self){
            $self->set('upper_title', strtoupper($self->get('title')));
        });
    }
```

Again, no success.

After dumping a mapper object, maybe this could help?

[image]

[image]

So it's visible as adhoc whatever that might be, but null as a property on a mapper object itself.

I can see that value is `NULL`, and the expression is what the value should be. That's why a get an empty output when doing `@post.upper_title` in a template, so how would you resolve this. When doing things normally expression takes the query string, and the value is the result of that query being executed, but here obviously that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Mapper` implementation is a little more complex as one would expect it without looking at the source code. First you shouldn't try to set non-existing mapper fields as the `Mapper` implementation interprets them as virtual fields which need to be derived by the database engine. That's also the reason why the values are `NULL`. Instead, you should use real class attributes (as said by ikkez).

*Hints*

- The `Mapper->cast()` method ignores class attributes so if one wants to use it one should adapt the `cast()` method, too.
- Defining virtual fields is also only effective before querying the database.

---

**Solution**

- Don't create (or update) virtual fields by calling `Mapper->set()` or setting `Mapper->field = …` (which calls internally `Mapper->set()`)
- Create class attributes instead
- Use the `ONLOAD` event to populate the attributes

---

**Snippet**

The following snippet shows how to use the `ONLOAD` trigger to define custom class attributes for storing programmatically derived values. An executable example is available at: https://gist.github.com/Rayne/fd24f5b664788cdf35956222ce790c02

```
/**
 * @property string title
 * @see https://gist.github.com/Rayne/fd24f5b664788cdf35956222ce790c02
 */
class TestMapper extends \DB\SQL\Mapper {
    /**
     * Custom mapper field which isn't backed and persisted by the database.
     *
     * @var null|string
     */
    public $upper_title;

    /**
     * @param \DB\SQL $sql
     */
    public function __construct(\DB\SQL $sql) {
        parent::__construct($sql, 'test');

        $this->onload(function (TestMapper $mapper) {
            $mapper->upper_title = strtoupper($mapper->title);
        });
    }
}
```

Read from the database:

```
$mapper = new TestMapper($sql);
for ($mapper->load(); !$mapper->dry(); $mapper->next()) {
    printf("title:       %s\n", $mapper->title);
    printf("upper_title: %s\n", $mapper->upper_title);
}
```

Result:

```
title:       Hello World
upper_title: HELLO WORLD
```

Comment: The only thing I may have unintentionally skipped over, is that I forgot to declare a class attribute.. The rest of it I did exactly the same. I will check this again when I come home. Thx

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting an empty string for `$mapper->upper_title`, were there any changes in how this works from previous version of a framework, as I am still on a version 3.5?

Comment: Also regarding yours: Don't create (or update) virtual fields by calling `Mapper->set()` or setting `Mapper->field = …` (which calls internally Mapper->set())

,and what the documentation says here: https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/cursor#Eventhandlers

`$self->source='bar'; // fails due to protected property named 'source'`
`$self->set('source','bar'); // works - just use the setter directly`

Comment: About the `Mapper->set()` and `Mapper->attribute`: It could be possible that my answer could be written better. I tried to say that you should only create "virtual fields" and only update "real fields (db columns)" if you want to create virtual fields or update existing columns. If you don't want to update a column and don't want to create a virtual (db derived) field then you have to create a real class attribute.

Comment: I have tested my linked code example with the tags `3.5.0`, `3.5.1` and `v3.6.0` (and `master` of course). I had to insert the test record manually for `3.5.0` as `Mapper` didn't want to create a record without primary key. I updated the linked code to be compatible with tag `3.5.0`. The `upper_title` was with every tested version as expected: `HELLO WORLD`.

Comment: Ok your example works. My bad, it was that in one place I used `$this` instead of closure argument(`$mapper`). But I find this very misleading in a documentation: 
> Notice: If you extend the mapper and try to read or modify mapper fields (especially those that also exist as class property) with magic getter/setter within those event handlers, you will get unpredictable behaviours or run into errors.

> The simple solution to this is to stick to the usage of the get or set methods from within the child class. These are safe to use and won't override protected properties.

Comment: So there is a mention of a mapper field that exists as class property, and that one should stick to the usage of `get` and `set`, I did like that and it wasn't working.. your way of setting them directly though worked well.

Comment: Also this now begs a question, should one use it that way or even like this maybe, where you define a method inside your class, then call it from template like `{{$post->isPublished()? ...:...}}`

      `public function isPublished()
      {
          return new \DateTime() >= new \DateTime($this->published_at);
      }`
Because this way you don't pollute the constructor. What would be the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the field, you want to use dynamically in the mapper, as property to the class and you should be able to use it on the fly:

```
class ModelA extends \DB\SQL\Mapper {

  public $stripped_tags;

}
```

Comment: Please see the amended question. Thanks.

Comment: in this case you need to calculate the property in a load event https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/cursor#onload

Comment: tried, but for some reason that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the best way is to define your own filter in templates. It is described [in the user guide](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.5/preview#filter). Feel free to let me know if you need more code than it is given there.